# Reading BIL and creating a time series in IDL

Tags: output, time-series, idl

I am having difficulties with writing a code in IDL to read 7200 BIL files. I am assuming that I will have to create a loop that reads over all of the files..? could anyone help as I am not familiar with either IDL coding or BIL files. 
Also, How do I create a 12 year time series for this large dataset? I have about 600 BIL files for each year from 2000 to 2012.

This is how I would usually create my time-series:

year = indgen(15)+2000
  outarr = transpose([[year], [outarr]])

Since I have multiple files for each year, what is the best way to create a time series?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the format of your BIL file?